# How do you write automated test for sql errors working with both H2 errors and MySQL errors?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, automated-tests, h2

I've read in multiple places it's a good practice to run tests using an in-memory H2 database to run them without the need to start an external SQL server. Ideally these tests should be able to run both in "local/in-memory" mode with an H2 database and in "integration" mode with a MySQL database.

I can see it works quite well for "happy path"/nominal scenarios, but how do you test error scenarios (error codes are not the same) ?

- H2 sql error codes : https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/api/ErrorCode.html
- MySQL error codes : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html

Here is a Jacoco coverage report of the code under test with H2 database, you can see the error code would be specific in the case of MySQL database, but we get only the default exception path with H2 database :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple/naive answer, but maybe not the best :

For ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR, it shouldn't be tested analyzing sql error code, but instead validated before the entity is sent to the database.

For ER_DUB_ENTRY, it can be tested by fetching potential duplicates before inserting, or by relying only on the generic message.

Please feel free to give a better answer, or I will accept my own.